# How do you print out a black box char in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I thought this would print out a black box: System.out.print('\u25A0');
But for some reason this only prints out question marks.

Comment: this works for me

Comment: Doesn't work for me in eclipse.

Comment: @shmosel works for me in eclipse

Comment: It can only work if your java default character encoding supports your character. I.e. on Macs this is typically UTF-8 but on Windows it may be some encoding that doesn't support your character at all. Even if the encoding does support your character, your terminal or whatever you're using to display your output may not support it.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the default windows encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The console window has to use a TrueType font in order to display Unicode. Unix can show it but if you are using Windows console, this console doesn't use font substitution, there's little you can do to make them show up. If you're using IDE like IntellijIdea inside windows, it doesn't treat console output as a grid of character cells, but rather a text stream (as is usual in Unix, but not Windows) and displays it accordingly.